# Android toolbar : Why three dots does not appear ?

Tags: android

Why I create toolbar I do not have three dots who will appear. How can I do ?

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="woowin.woowin.Main">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#393939"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

And can you explain me, how add options in this three dots after that ?

thank you

Comment: this is called option menu and you can add item into it by edit in .xml file. which is in `res -> menu -> activity_main` defaultly

Answer (score 4):

you forgot to add your menu in your activity use below code to add menu

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);
        return true; 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add at least one menu item either via XML or in java code using [`add`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#add(int,%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) into your menu to see the menu options

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(0,0,0,"title");
    return true;
}
```